# Touchpad cursor freezes while installing software (Inspiron 5000)

Tags: freeze, touchpad, dell-inspiron, cursor

My touchpads cursor freezes while installing software. It happens whenever I install or update Windows, out of the blue, the cursor freezes, but I can still use the keyboard. I also connected an USB mouse and it worked while the touchpad was frozen. The problem seems to be with the touchpad. I am not sure if it's software or hardware.

Help!